# What is wrong with the CSS of this template that makes it partially broken

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

After searching for a while, I found this WordPress template http://demo.wpmultiverse.com/newsted/ that suits my simple needs. But the problem that I am having is the responsive feature of this tempalate's homepage. All the other pages work fine while the homepage is broken when I resize the width of my browser to be that of a mobile screen. Even if I view it from my mobile screen it is broken.

I tried clearing the divs and I have messed around with the CSS for some time now but I can't get to the root of the problem. I am unable to understand why other pages work fine with the same CSS style and only the homepage with the posts list is messed up.

Comment: It would be best if you posted some excerpts of your code (particularly the css) rather than pasting a link to the template page, as that isn't really going to tell us anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on your custom css:

```
#primary-sidebar .widget {
float: left;
}
```

But you still need to set the media queries for mobile and tablet
and put the code above.

use this one:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
#primary-sidebar .widget {
float: left;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will have to do for now.

Comment: This is the link for complete list of media queries for different devices.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you mimicode, I was looking for the list but I didn't know what to call the list so I was unable to search for it.